# QT4 > QT5 for uri.queryItems();

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qurl

I am currently trying to translate this old code meant for QT4 into today's QT5. I need some help with the following:

```
bool parseBitcoinURI(const QUrl &uri, SendCoinsRecipient *out)
{
    // return if URI is not valid or is no bitcoin URI
    if(!uri.isValid() || uri.scheme() != QString("dimecoin"))
        return false;

    SendCoinsRecipient rv;
    rv.address = uri.path();
    rv.amount = 0;
    QList<QPair<QString, QString> > items = uri.queryItems();
    for (QList<QPair<QString, QString> >::iterator i = items.begin(); i != items.end(); i++)
```

From the above I am getting a:

```
error: no member named 'queryItems' in 'QUrl'
    QList<QPair<QString, QString> > items = uri.queryItems();
                                            ~~~ ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt5 you have to use [QUrlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurlquery.html):

```
[...]
rv.amount = 0;
QUrlQuery query(uri);
QList<QPair<QString, QString> > items = query.queryItems();
```

Comment: Thank you! but now I get: `error: variable has incomplete type 'QUrlQuery'
    QUrlQuery query(uri)` and ` forward declaration of 'QUrlQuery'
class QUrlQuery;`

Comment: @JulesMoretti add `#include <QUrlQuery>`